# Maximum but still limited magnitude region is not plotted with ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

[image]

The function is well defined in the whole region. But it just skips plotting the center region. I've tried PlotPoints, Mesh, Contours - it didn't help.

[image]

After making more contours. White hole is still there.

[image]

After zooming in the region suddenly reveals data.

How can I make it to plot central part in detail when zoomed out? Thank you in advance.

UPD: Yes, thanks, that's PlotRange :)

Comment: `PlotRange -> All`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I extend my comment to decrease the number of unanswered questions.

Just add `PlotRange -> All`

```
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]